# Unwanted color blending

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Im drawing two rectangles. One is orange, and the other is pink.

```
 spriteBatch.Draw(texture, mainRect, mainColor_Current);
 spriteBatch.Draw(texture, goalRect, goalColor_Current);
```

They use the same texture, only with different colors. 
Somehow i end up with this.
[image]
The white isn't its own square, its just the half of the pink square that overlaps with the orange square.

Why is this? And how do i fix it?

(also, the texture I'm using is a 1x1 white pixel with no alpha channel).

Comment: What is the desired outcome? Have you tried passing a different `BlendState` to `spriteBatch.Begin()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i needed to pass `BlendState.Opaque` into `SpriteBatch.Begin()`.

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, BlendState.Opaque);
```